# curl connection to parse-server sometimes fails

Tags: curl, parse-platform, connection, ubuntu-14.04, parse-server

I run a saveObject CURL POST from a remote terminal to a newly installed parse-server and the query works like below:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: appLetsMeet" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sammy","cheatMode":false}' http://xxxx.xxx:1338/parse/classes/GameScore
{"objectId":"QrnlsqEWuY","createdAt":"2016-05-12T10:15:46.552Z"}
```

and sometimes fails when the query is sent consecutively like below

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxxx.xxx port 1338: Connection refused
```

I'm running parse-server on port 1338 on a digital ocean site with SSL disabled on both mongodb and parse-server (--allowInsecureHTTP true) so all requests are through http:// not https://

I can access the parse-server via the dashboard so I think the installations are somewhat correct.

Is there some sort of throttling going on?

Can anybody help?

[UPDATE]
I was running the parse-server with PM2. When run separately, this issue stopped happening. HMMMMMM